# XML Schema validation error

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have my xml file as

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <Info>
 <Pan>123</Pan>
 <Name>qwe</Name>
 <Email>qwe</Email>
 <City>qwe</City>
 <State>qwe</State>
 <AssessmentYear>2012</AssessmentYear>
 <MobileNo>1234</MobileNo>
 <Income-Salary>1234</Income-Salary>
 <Income-Other>1234</Income-Other>
 <TotalAmount>122</TotalAmount>
<Signature> 
<SignedInfo>
 <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116"><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
Pan : <xsl:copy-of select="//Pan"/>

MobileNo : <xsl:copy-of select="//MobileNo"/>

TotalAmount : <xsl:copy-of select="//TotalAmount"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><DigestValue>FgbIIimTLIbd0Zpvq1zDrZse6aJg5bAE1/Q58cEkEvk=</DigestValue></Reference>
 </SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>dy4QDco5NhXResncu0tUG5ylujDn9siIQSHjuX5HxH2gs70LpsO3KDWNvDXjpgkIySYfzJ/FdC6C
trkSySWRjhObqI8cbcP5VU/nL8pP21+3CO+gF1k884aeX3felpRy0FBBMTYBknQTunWCHvpHk927
ZHGvm6Hiej7iBKr3e1k=</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
</Info>
```

My Schema files for this xml file is as follows(**c1.xsd**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="C:\\xml\\c2.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="Info">
  <xs:complexType>

  <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Pan" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="AssessmentYear" type="xs:gYear"/>
      <xs:element name="MobileNo" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="Income-Salary" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="Income-Other" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="TotalAmount" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
 </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**c2.xsd(Edited)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xs:element name="Signature">
     <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SignedInfo">
         <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="CanonicalizationMethod">
              <xs:complexType>
               <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
              </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
             <xs:element name="SignatureMethod">
               <xs:complexType>
                 <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
               </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>                
            <xs:element name="Reference">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string"/>
               <xs:all>
               <xs:element name="Transforms">
                 <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="Transform" type="xs:string">
                       <xs:complexType>
                         <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                       </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                   </xs:sequence>
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="DigestMethod">
                 <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                 </xs:complexType>
               </xs:element>
               <xs:element name="DigestValue" type="xs:hexBinary"/>
               </xs:all>
             </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:complexType> 
        </xs:element> 
       <xs:element name="SignatureValue" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When I validate my xml file i get the following Exception

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C://xml//c2.xsd; lineNumber: 22;
columnNumber: 37; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_Reference
SignedInfoSignature' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or oc
curs too often.
```

**I cannot figure out where am I going wrong? Can anyone tell where exactly is the mistake in my code?**
*Error after Edit 1*

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C://xml//c2.xsd; lineNumber: 22;
columnNumber: 15; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_Reference
SignedInfoSignature' is invalid.  Element 'all' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs
 too often.
```

Answer (score 2):

At c2.xsd, line 22

```
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string"/>
           <xs:element name="Transforms">
```

`xs:element` cannot appear as a direct child of `xs:complexType`. It must be inside `xs:all`, `xs:choice` or `xs:sequence`.

Comment: Check my c2.xsd now. I tried <xs:all> but still it shows error. I pasted the new error in my question itself

Answer (score 1):

I tried out your file and managed to get it to validate against notepad++ doing a couple of things:

1. Changed the xsd to use a reference to the imported signature xsd without any c:\reference.  To do this I just copied that imported file to the same location as the xsd I was doing the importing from
2. Changed the c2.xsd where you specify the ds to a different attribute namely dsig
3. Downloaded the w3c version of the signature xsd from [w3 Signature xsd](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd) and used that in the import (Step 1).
4. Changed your output xml to include the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" line when specifying the signature.

Note the xsd and xml I succeeded in validating in notepad++ below.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<xs:element name="Info">
  <xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Pan" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="AssessmentYear" type="xs:gYear"/>
      <xs:element name="MobileNo" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="Income-Salary" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="Income-Other" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element name="TotalAmount" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
      <xs:element ref="dsig:Signature" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <Info xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
 <Pan>123</Pan>
 <Name>qwe</Name>
 <Email>qwe</Email>
 <City>qwe</City>
 <State>qwe</State>
 <AssessmentYear>2012</AssessmentYear>
 <MobileNo>1234</MobileNo>
 <Income-Salary>1234</Income-Salary>
 <Income-Other>1234</Income-Other>
 <TotalAmount>122</TotalAmount>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
<SignedInfo>
 <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
 <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
 <Reference URI="">
 <Transforms>
 <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
 <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116">
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
Pan : <xsl:copy-of select="//Pan"/>

MobileNo : <xsl:copy-of select="//MobileNo"/>

TotalAmount : <xsl:copy-of select="//TotalAmount"/>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</Transform>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
<DigestValue>FgbIIimTLIbd0Zpvq1zDrZse6aJg5bAE1/Q58cEkEvk=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
 </SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>dy4QDco5NhXResncu0tUG5ylujDn9siIQSHjuX5HxH2gs70LpsO3KDWNvDXjpgkIySYfzJ/FdC6C
trkSySWRjhObqI8cbcP5VU/nL8pP21+3CO+gF1k884aeX3felpRy0FBBMTYBknQTunWCHvpHk927
ZHGvm6Hiej7iBKr3e1k=</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
</Info>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your c2.xsd remains invalid, look on ComplexType definition:

```
<complexType
  id=ID
  name=NCName
  abstract=true|false
  mixed=true|false
  block=(#all|list of (extension|restriction))
  final=(#all|list of (extension|restriction))
  any attributes
 >

 (annotation?,(simpleContent|complexContent|((group|all|
 choice|sequence)?,((attribute|attributeGroup)*,anyAttribute?))))

</complexType>
```

attribute must be defined after group, all, choice or sequence element, so change order in `<xs:element name="Reference">` in order to define first `<xs:all>` and then `<xs:attribute>`:

```
      <xs:element name="Reference">
         <xs:complexType>
           <xs:all>
           <xs:element name="Transforms">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element name="Transform" type="xs:string">
                   <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                   </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
               </xs:sequence>
             </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="DigestMethod">
             <xs:complexType>
               <xs:attribute name="Algorithm" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
             </xs:complexType>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="DigestValue" type="xs:hexBinary"/>
           </xs:all>
           <xs:attribute name="URI" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```