# Validate XML with multiple namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML document using two XSD and I want to validate it.
First of all, I retrieve all XSD used and add them in an `XmlSchemaSet`.
Next, I read my document with an `XmlReader`. If this works perfectly with an Xml with only one namespace, It fails when I try to validate my XML with two namespace or more like this :

```
    <element1>
         <LMSG:element2>value</LMSG:element2>
    </element1>
```

Do you have a work around for it ?

Thanks for your help

-EDIT-

here is my function to load all my XSD to validate my file (It retrieve the XSD depending on a country standards):

```
    public XmlSchemaSet GetAllXSDUsed(String strCountrySpecific, String strCurrentXSDPath, XmlNode currentNode = null)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet xSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
        if (currentNode == null)
            currentNode = this;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentNode.NamespaceURI))
        {
            String strXsdName = currentNode.NamespaceURI.Substring(currentNode.NamespaceURI.LastIndexOf(':') + 1) + ".xsd";
            String strPath = strCurrentXSDPath;
            XmlSchema schema = null;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strCountrySpecific) && File.Exists(Path.Combine(strPath, strCountrySpecific, strXsdName)))
                schema = xSet.Add(currentNode.NamespaceURI, Path.Combine(strPath, strCountrySpecific, strXsdName));
            else if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(strPath, strXsdName)))
                schema = xSet.Add(currentNode.NamespaceURI, Path.Combine(strPath, strXsdName));
        }

        foreach (XmlNode node in currentNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            XmlSchemaSet newxSet = GetAllXSDUsed(strCountrySpecific, strCurrentXSDPath, currentNode: node);
            if (newxSet.Count > 0)
                foreach (XmlSchema xs in newxSet.Schemas())
                    if (!xSet.Contains(xs.TargetNamespace))
                        xSet.Add(xs);
        }

        return xSet;
    }
```

The problem is maybe that I specify the prefix used nowhere.

Here is the error that I get : `The element 'CBISDDReqLogMsg' has invalid child element 'GrpHdr' in namespace 'urn:CBI:xsd:CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.00.06'. List of possible elements expected: 'GrpHdr'.` for this block :

```
    <CBISDDReqLogMsg>
            <LMSG:GrpHdr xmlns:LMSG="urn:CBI:xsd:CBISDDReqLogMsg.00.00.06">
                    <LMSG:MsgId>Value</LMSG:MsgId>
```

Note that the prefix 'LMSG' is also declared at the root of the document.

Comment: Can you post the code that loads/adds the XSDs?  Can post what the validation errors are?

Comment: Hi Moby Disk, I added the code you asked !

Comment: It looks like it actually does NOT want the namespace.  It is saying that it expected an element <GrpHdr> not an element <LMSG:GrpHdr>.  So could this be your answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007881/why-is-my-xml-validation-failing-against-its-schema